# python: Replace specific string order with some other string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the following text:

```
text = je vais mettre la {\i1}i{\i0}-ème équation, donc {\i1}aᵢ₁x₁+{\i0} … + {\i1}aᵢₙxₙ= bi{\i0} et ensuite, je ne change pas les autres
```

I would like to replace to replace all instances `{\i1}SOMETHING{\i0}` with `\textit{SOMETHING}`

Is this possible with Python ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please have a look at the `re` standard module.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and there are multiple ways to do this. Have you tried something, did it work, and just where are you stuck? This could be done easily with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If you are not familiar with those, you could repeatedly search for the initial part of the desired substring then the final part then deal with the section.

Comment: If you are not used to regex format you can use a site like https://regex101.com/ to build/test your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub(r'{\\i1}(.*?){\\i0}', r'\textit{\1}', text)
```

An explanation. You must replace all sub-string (character sequences) that match a precise pattern:

- a fixed string: "{\i1}";
- some generic text you do not know right now (SOMETHING);
- a fixed string: "{\i0}";

with the following text: "\textit{SOMETHING}", where SOMETHING is exactly the same text as above. Regular expressions are perfect for this kind of job. With them you can search text, capture it in a variable, replace, etc. The syntax, related to your need, is the following:

- the literal string "{\i1}", the double backslash is needed because the backslash is a special character;
- the dot (`.`) match every character
- the start-question-mark (`*?`) repeat the previous pattern (the dot) in a non-greedy fashion. Combined with the previous token means any character as less as possible;
- the parenthesis (`()`) store the content pattern in a special variable (`\1`, `\2`, etc.) that you can reference later in the replacement text;
- the literal string "{\i0}".

Using `re.sub` you can replace the matching pattern with a replacement text. I suggest you to follow the @cglacet advice and test your regular expression with regex101: https://regex101.com/r/8vaDFt/1

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I am completely new to regular expressions, would you mind to tell me how it works ?

Comment: Regular expressions are a series of pattern that are matched against a string. They are a powerful tool to parse and manipulate text. The argument is so big that are many book dedicated entirely to it. I can only point you to the documentation of the python library (but they are language agnostic) and to the wikipedia article.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you just add a comment of what the code does roughly ? I will then try to understand it on my own using your provided link.